# Usar el DISTINCT en el where

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM UMD_CONSEN1.CONSV_CONSENT con1 WHERE con1.IDEN_ID_IDENTIFIER ='59674487831438266215227000947110082702' AND PURP_ID_PURPOSE='2'
```

ahora me han dicho que debo filtrar por el campo COST_ID_CONSENT_STATUS de manera que salgan sin repetir. (si hay 2 con el mimso estatus que salga solo 1). Ademas de las que se repiten debe de salir la que tenga la fecha mas actual CONV_TI_PROMPTED_DATE.

He montado esta consulta pero me sigue sacando 3 resultado y no 2 como debria xq no me saca los del status diferente

```
SELECT * FROM UMD_CONSEN1.CONSV_CONSENT con1 WHERE con1.IDEN_ID_IDENTIFIER ='59674487831438266215227000947110082702' AND PURP_ID_PURPOSE='2' and exists(select 1 from UMD_CONSEN1.CONSV_CONSENT con2 where
con1.COST_ID_CONSENT_STATUS not like con2.COST_ID_CONSENT_STATUS);
```

Comment: sera... distinct? igual, eso es tu enunciado, y a mi me suena que necesitas group by....

Comment: he leido varios post pero no soy capaz de implentarlo

Comment: y como podriamos saber magicamente porque te salen 3 filas y no 2? :/

Comment: Lo que te intentan decir es que necesitamos que nos brindes toda la información necesaria para reproducir tu problema. Más info [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que solo falta en DISTINCT en tu consulta.

podrías leer https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx para ver un ejemplo del uso en la sentencia SQL

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar distinct o utilizar GROUP BY para agrupar los campos iguales, pero si utilizas GROUP BY tendrás que utilizar HAVING para la condición que indicas de la fecha

Comment: para un gruop by no puedo poner select *